# Populate A List from Parse.com

Tags: android, listview, parse-platform

I am trying to get a column of  Strings from parse.com and load them to ListView using ArrayAdapter.
It seems in the log the the String array I am trying to load is empty (written then "storage=null").
I don't get what is the problem.
I am loading the Strings from parse in the MainActivity, and then initializing the adapter with the String array I created before that.
Thanks in advance.

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView list;
String[] itemname ;
String[] Strings;
Integer[] imgid={
        R.drawable.one,
        R.drawable.one,
        R.drawable.one,
        R.drawable.one,
        R.drawable.one,
        R.drawable.one,
        R.drawable.one,
        R.drawable.one,
};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Song");
    query.orderByDescending("updatedAt");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(List<ParseObject> songs, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                 Strings = new String[songs.size()-1];
                for (int i = 0; i < songs.size()-1; i++) {
                    ParseObject object = songs.get(i);
                    String songName = object.getString("name");
                    Strings[i] = songName;
                }
            } else {
                Log.d("error", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });

    CustomListAdapter adapter=new CustomListAdapter(this, Strings);

    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String Slecteditem= itemname[+position];
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Slecteditem, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Adapter

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private final Activity context;
    private final String[] itemname;

    public CustomListAdapter(Activity context, String[] itemname) {
        super(context, R.layout.content_main, itemname);

        this.context=context;
        this.itemname=itemname;
    }


public  TextView extratxt;
    public View getView(int position,View view,ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.line_single, null,true);

        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.Poet);
        TextView dayView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.Day);
         extratxt = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.SongaName);

        txtTitle.setText("hello");
        dayView.setText("D");

        extratxt.setText("Description " + itemname[position]);

        return rowView;

        };
    }
```

Log(Error)

```
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: storage == null
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2378)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2440)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:162)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5430)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:913)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:706)
                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: storage == null
                                                                             at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.<init>(Arrays.java:38)
                                                                             at java.util.Arrays.asList(Arrays.java:155)
                                                                             at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:128)
                                                                             at shirapp.israel.nir_zabari.shira.CustomListAdapter.<init>(CustomListAdapter.java:16)
                                                                             at shirapp.israel.nir_zabari.shira.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:62)
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6097)
                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2331)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2440) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:162) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349) 
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5430) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:913) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:706)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting that error because Strings array is null when it's passed to the adapter.

I changed Strings from String[] to ArrayList and instantieted it in onCreate and after you add the new songs to the list call              adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() to let the adapter know that new items have been added to the list and refresh it.

Here is the updated class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView list;
    CustomListAdapter adapter;
    String[] itemname ;
    ArrayList<String> Strings;
    Integer[] imgid={
            R.drawable.one,
            R.drawable.one,
            R.drawable.one,
            R.drawable.one,
            R.drawable.one,
            R.drawable.one,
            R.drawable.one,
            R.drawable.one,
    };
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        Strings = new ArrayList();

        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Song");
        query.orderByDescending("updatedAt");
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            public void done(List<ParseObject> songs, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < songs.size() - 1; i++) {
                        ParseObject object = songs.get(i);
                        String songName = object.getString("name");
                        Strings.add(songName);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d("error", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });

        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, Strings);

        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String Slecteditem= itemname[+position];
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Slecteditem, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, sounds reasonable. Thank you. 
For the one's who might see this question, you'll also need to change the adapter.

Comment: Right sorry, yeah change from String[] to ArrayList<String>.